# Plotting x,y,z with intervals

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How do I plot xyz In rectangular, polar, and 3-D?

```
for x = 0 to 35pi:
Y = x*sin(x)
Z = x*cos(x)
```

Using the the intervals of X which provides very smooth plots . Create three plots including tittle and labels .

---

This is the input I have put in so far. I'm not sure if this is correct:

```
x = pi*linspace(0,35);
y = pi*x,sin(pi*x);
z = pi*x,cos(pi*x);

plot3(x,y,z)
title('data analysis')
xlabel('independent x')
ylabel('dependent y')
zlabel('z')
```

Comment: What have you tried. Is this home work?

Comment: I've tried x=linspace(0;35).  Y=x*sin(x). Z=x*cos(x) ... I'm not sure how to add "pi" in my intervals

Comment: x = pi*linspace(0,35);
y = pi*x,sin(pi*x);
z = pi*x,cos(pi*x);

plot3(x,y,z)
title('data analysis')
xlabel('independent x')
ylabel('dependent y')
zlabel('z')

Comment: @chessofnerd x = pi*linspace(0,35); y = pi*x,sin(pi*x); z = pi*x,cos(pi*x);  plot3(x,y,z) title('data analysis') xlabel('independent x') ylabel('dependent y') zlabel('z')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this solves the problem as you describe it:

```
x = linspace(0, 35*pi, 10000);
y = x .* sin(x);
z = x .* cos(x);

plot3(x, y, z);
title('data analysis');
xlabel('independent x');
ylabel('dependent y');
zlabel('z');
```